# How to calculate the percentages of multiple columns in a tbl list in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, percentage, tidyr

Suppose I have a list (in tbl format) like this:

```
       Type.1 count averageTotal averageHP averageAttack averageDefense averageSpAtk averageSp..Def averageSpeed
       (fctr) (int)        (dbl)     (dbl)         (dbl)          (dbl)        (dbl)          (dbl)        (dbl)
 1       Bug    69     378.9275  56.88406      70.97101       70.72464     53.86957       64.79710     61.68116
 2      Dark    31     445.7419  66.80645      88.38710       70.22581     74.64516       69.51613     76.16129
 3    Dragon    32     550.5312  83.31250     112.12500       86.37500     96.84375       88.84375     83.03125
 4  Electric    44     443.4091  59.79545      69.09091       66.29545     90.02273       73.70455     84.50000
 5     Fairy    17     413.1765  74.11765      61.52941       65.70588     78.52941       84.70588     48.58824
```

If I want to calculate the percentage of each column out of the averageTotal column (for each row), how would I proceed?

Specifically, my desired result would be like this:

```
      Type.1 count averageTotal averageHP averageAttack averageDefense averageSpAtk averageSp..Def averageSpeed
      (fctr) (int)        (dbl)     (dbl)         (dbl)          (dbl)        (dbl)          (dbl)        (dbl)
1       Bug    69     378.9275    15.02%       18.73%         18.73%        14.21%       17.11%     16.29%
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple method in base R:

```
df[, 4:9] <- df[, 4:9] / df[[3]]
```

which returns

```
df
    Type.1 count averageTotal averageHP averageAttack averageDefense averageSpAtk averageSp..Def averageSpeed
1      Bug    69     378.9275 0.1501186     0.1872944      0.1866443    0.1421633      0.1710013    0.1627783
2     Dark    31     445.7419 0.1498770     0.1982921      0.1575481    0.1674627      0.1559560    0.1708641
3   Dragon    32     550.5312 0.1513311     0.2036669      0.1568939    0.1759096      0.1613782    0.1508202
4 Electric    44     443.4091 0.1348539     0.1558175      0.1495131    0.2030241      0.1662225    0.1905689
5    Fairy    17     413.1765 0.1793850     0.1489180      0.1590262    0.1900626      0.2050114    0.1175968
```

The numbers refer to the column positions, so the third column divides columns four through nine. This is reported in proportions rather than percentages, but you could fix this pretty easily with

```
df[, 4:9] <- round(100 * df[, 4:9] / df[[3]], 2)
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="       Type.1 count averageTotal averageHP averageAttack averageDefense averageSpAtk averageSp..Def averageSpeed
                 1       Bug    69     378.9275  56.88406      70.97101       70.72464     53.86957       64.79710     61.68116
                 2      Dark    31     445.7419  66.80645      88.38710       70.22581     74.64516       69.51613     76.16129
                 3    Dragon    32     550.5312  83.31250     112.12500       86.37500     96.84375       88.84375     83.03125
                 4  Electric    44     443.4091  59.79545      69.09091       66.29545     90.02273       73.70455     84.50000
                 5     Fairy    17     413.1765  74.11765      61.52941       65.70588     78.52941       84.70588     48.58824")
```

Comment: Thanks! It's indeed very simple and elegant!

Answer (score 1):

With dplyr, you can use `mutate_at` to specify which columns to change, with a custom function defined in `funs` where `.` represents the column being mutated:

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(averageHP:averageSpeed), funs(. / averageTotal * 100))

## # A tibble: 5 × 9
##     Type.1 count averageTotal averageHP averageAttack averageDefense averageSpAtk averageSp..Def
##     <fctr> <int>        <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl>          <dbl>        <dbl>          <dbl>
## 1      Bug    69     378.9275  15.01186      18.72944       18.66443     14.21633       17.10013
## 2     Dark    31     445.7419  14.98770      19.82921       15.75481     16.74627       15.59560
## 3   Dragon    32     550.5312  15.13311      20.36669       15.68939     17.59096       16.13782
## 4 Electric    44     443.4091  13.48539      15.58175       14.95131     20.30241       16.62225
## 5    Fairy    17     413.1765  17.93850      14.89180       15.90262     19.00626       20.50114
## # ... with 1 more variables: averageSpeed <dbl>
```

Comment: Thanks! Good to know what . can do in dplyr :)